# Java - BufferedReader, read() missing chars

Tags: java

sorry for my silly question, I've been playing around with BufferedReader class and realised I can not figure this out on my own, and hope that someone will be able to explain it to me. Big thanks in advance.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int i = 0;
        int current;
        do {
            current = reader.read();
            System.out.println(current);
        }
        while (reader.read() != -1);
        
        reader.close();

        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

After I run my code and feed in sample input, example `"one   two  three"`.
Output:

```
111 //o
101 //e
32 //" "
116 //t
111 //o
32 //" "
104 //h
101 //e
10 // new line
```

Resulting in some chars missed, and several spaces treated as one 32, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your characters are getting list here: `        while (reader.read() != -1);
`

Comment: Every time you use `reader.read()` it consumes a character, so when you use this `while (reader.read() != -1);` you actually lose a character.

Comment: Traditional way is to use `while((current = reader.read()) != -1) {` loop.

Comment: Oh jeez, I knew the answer will make me feel silly, but I did not expect it to be this simple, thanks a lot tho folks!